# Value are not storing in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

When i put the value from this page its not saving my value in database. The program stopped on this link www.mywebsite.com/index.php?admin/manage_language/update_phrase/english and show a blank page. whenever i run on my local machine its run successfully. update the record and come back to again on www.mywebsite.com/index.php?admin/manage_language/edit_phrase/english on this link. But on my cpanel its not working well.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-bordered mb-3">
                <?php if(isset($edit_profile)):?>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#edit" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-link active">
                        <?php echo get_phrase('edit_phrase');?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php endif;?>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#list" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link <?php if(!isset($edit_profile))echo 'active';?>">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-home-variant d-lg-none d-block mr-1"></i>
                        <span class="d-none d-lg-block"><?php echo get_phrase('language_list');?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#add" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-account-circle d-lg-none d-block mr-1"></i>
                        <span class="d-none d-lg-block"><?php echo get_phrase('add_phrase');?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#add_lang" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-settings-outline d-lg-none d-block mr-1"></i>
                        <span class="d-none d-lg-block"><?php echo get_phrase('add_language');?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <!----PHRASE EDITING TAB STARTS-->
                <?php if (isset($edit_profile)):?>
                <div class="tab-pane show active" id="edit" style="padding: 30px">
                    <div class="">


                            <div class="row">
                            <?php
                            $current_editing_language   =   $edit_profile;
                            echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/manage_language/update_phrase/english' , array('id' => 'phrase_form'));
                            $count = 1;
                            $language_phrases   =   $this->db->query("SELECT `phrase_id` , `phrase` , `$current_editing_language` FROM `language`")->result_array();
                            foreach($language_phrases as $row)
                            {
                                $count++;
                                $phrase_id          =   $row['phrase_id'];                  //id number of phrase
                                $phrase             =   $row['phrase'];                     //basic phrase text
                                $phrase_language    =   $row[$current_editing_language];    //phrase of current editing language
                                ?>
                                <!----phrase box starts-->
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="tile-stats tile-gray">
                                        <div class="icon"><i class="entypo-mail"></i></div>


                                        <h5><?php echo $row['phrase'];?></h5>
                                        <p>
                                            <input type="text" name="phrase<?php echo $row['phrase_id'];?>"
                                                value="<?php echo $phrase_language;?>" class="form-control"/>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <!----phrase box ends-->
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="total_phrase" value="<?php echo $count;?>" />
                            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo get_phrase('update_phrase');?>" onClick="document.getElementById('phrase_form').submit();" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                            <?php
                            echo form_close();
                            ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif;?>
                <!----PHRASE EDITING TAB ENDS-->
                <!----TABLE LISTING STARTS-->
                <div class="tab-pane <?php if(!isset($edit_profile))echo 'show active';?>" id="list">

                    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-centered mb-0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><?php echo get_phrase('language');?></th>
                                    <th><?php echo get_phrase('option');?></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                        $fields = $this->db->list_fields('language');
                                        foreach($fields as $field)
                                        {
                                             if($field == 'phrase_id' || $field == 'phrase')continue;
                                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo ucwords($field);?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_language/edit_phrase/<?php echo $field;?>"
                                             class="btn btn-info">
                                                <?php echo get_phrase('edit_phrase');?>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_language/delete_language/<?php echo $field;?>"
                                              class="btn btn-danger">
                                                <?php echo get_phrase('delete_language');?>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!----TABLE LISTING ENDS--->


                <!----PHRASE CREATION FORM STARTS---->
                <div class="tab-pane box" id="add" style="padding: 30px">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/manage_language/add_phrase/' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate', 'style' => 'width:100%;'));?>
                            <div class="padded">
                                <div class="form-group justify-content-md-center">
                                    <label class="col-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('phrase');?></label>
                                    <div class="col-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phrase" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>" placeholder="e.g. name, email"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><?php echo get_phrase('add_phrase');?></button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                        <?php echo form_close();?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!----PHRASE CREATION FORM ENDS--->

                <!----ADD NEW LANGUAGE---->
                <div class="tab-pane box" id="add_lang" style="padding: 30px">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/manage_language/add_language/' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate', 'style' => 'width:100%;'));?>
                            <div class="padded">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('language');?></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="language" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>" placeholder="e.g. Spanish, Portugese"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><?php echo get_phrase('add_language');?></button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                        <?php echo form_close();?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!----LANGUAGE ADDING FORM ENDS-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);                                                                                                    Turn error reporting true and tell me which error you are getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)